# Using jQuery to align an element to mouse location has an offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a mapping feature and the jQuery script that aligns the element to the mouse location has an offset that seems to match the page spacing.

Here is the testing area http://champagnecentre.com/dev/directory/

```
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
   jQuery('.directory-listing').css({top:e.pageY,left:e.pageX});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: One thing I noticed is the `.directory-listing` divs aren't nested under a `postition: relative;` element, as far as I can tell. When I added `position: relative;` to one of the parent elements, it helped with the positioning. It doesn't make it correct, but it brings it closer

Comment: This is demo: https://smalinux.github.io/svgTemp.html and you could download codes from here: https://github.com/smalinux/smalinux.github.io/blob/master/svgTemp.html

Answer (score 1):

@Bwolfing is right I believe. `e.pageY` and `e.pageX` relate to the document. As your div is nested the `top` and `left` positions are relative to the parent, which is leading to the offset.

by using `.parent().offset()` we can workout the offsets, fiddle below. I've added `.area` as a displaced div in which to nest `.directory-listing`, the `.mousemove` function can be attributed to `$(document)...` or `$('.area')...`, note that `.mousemove` is better written a subject of `.on`:

```js
$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function(e) {
    // special effects
  },
  mousemove: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $('.directory-listing'),
      d = target.parent().offset(), // this gets the offset positions
      dX = d.left + 6,
      dY = d.top + 12; // the +6 and +12 here are just to center the 'x'
    target.css({
      left: e.pageX - dX,
      top: e.pageY - dY
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
    // special effects
  },
  click: function(e) {
    // special effects
  }
});
```

```css
.area {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid #09f;
}
.directory-listing {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="area">
  <div class="directory-listing">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As per @Bwolfing's comment below, my interpretation of the spec was incorrect. I have updated the plunk below to propose an alternate solution to that proposed above. Changing the position of the tooltip to `fixed` forces it to be relative to the page.

https://plnkr.co/8CCns5mwdqSoWiGK1SDN

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="offsetWrapper">
      <h1 id="myH1">Hello Plunker!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on ('mousemove', function (event)
{
  $('#myH1').css ({'left', event.pageX, 'top', event.pageY});
});
```

**CSS**

```
#myH1 {
  position: fixed;

  margin: 0;
}

.offsetWrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;

  /*Show the position of the container for reference*/
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: `$.css({top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX})` is just a short hand. If you pass an [object to `$.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) it treats the keys as style properties and the values as the style value. In other words, your suggested fix is what Michael is already doing. More likely, the issue is the div being moved is relative to the wrong element

Comment: @Bwolfing You are correct. I'm not sure how, but I missed that completely in the spec, and this is the first I've ever seen it used in practice. My apologies.